# How to COUNT DISTINCT on more than one column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following table.

```
group _id   p_id    version value
1              1       1    10
1              1       2    11
1              1       2    12
1              2       3    13
2              1       2    14
2              1       3    15
2              1       2    16
```

I would like to count on how many records for each group_id and how many distinct p_id + version for each group_id. I have following query

```
SELECT "group_id",count(*) , count(distinct "p_id","version")
FROM tbl
group by "group_id"
```

Aapparently, it' not going to work, as Oracle will give me error on COUNT

```
ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments
```

I know this can be done by subquery. However, is there any simple way to get same result? Considing the performance is important to me, as we have more than 500 million records in the table.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c9217/5)

Comment: Do you just want this? -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c9217/9

Comment: Subquery isn't necessarily slower. Oracle is especially good at optimizing those.

Comment: @bluefeet, I would like to have CONT(*) and COUNT(DISTINCT) in same query result.

Comment: WRT performance, how often do what to run this query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if it's the best way, but I normally concatenate the two values, using a delimiter to enforce "distinctness", so they become one expression, which Oracle can handle with `COUNT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT "group_id",count(*) , count(distinct "p_id" || '-' || "version")
FROM tbl
group by "group_id"
```

Comment: Nice! haven't thought about this before. I will try it now